# What can I replace with the sleep command in the Windows variant of ncurses?

Tags: c++, c, ncurses, curses, pdcurses

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    initscr();
    mvaddstr(10, 10, "Hello, world");
    refresh();
    sleep(4);
    endwin();
    std::cout << "DONE\n";
}
```

I'm working on a project and I need to take down the curses windows for a while just to write a path to directory in cmd and then let the curses windows come back. I found this code on this site and tried to use sleep command in the code but it didn't work.

So if anyone knew how to solve this please write it down here. Thnx :)

Comment: `#include <thread>\n#include <chrono>\nusing namespace std::literals;\nstd::this_thread::sleep_for(4s);`

Comment: Are you mixing C and C++ languages?  You have both tagged.  I don't recommend mixing the two, as that will complicate your program and make the program more difficult to get running.  They are different languages.  For example, the C language allows overloading of functions and operators; the C language doesn'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`napms`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_kernel.3x.html#h3-napms) is the (portable) curses function to use instead of **`sleep`**